# A definite integral

Tags: integration, exponential-function

$$\int_0^1\sqrt{\left(3-3t^2\right)^2+\left(6t\right)^2}\,dt$$

I am trying to take this integral. I know the answer is 4.
But I am having trouble taking the integral itself.
I've tried foiling and the simplifying. I've tried u-sub. I just can't get the correct way to take the integral.
Any help would be appreciated. Sorry if the layout doesn't look right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : By doing some manipulation and expansion, notice that
$$\begin{align}
(3-3t^2)^2 + (6t)^2 &= 3^2(1-2t^2 +t^4 +4t^2)\\
&= 9(1+ 2t^2 + t^4) \\
&=9(1+t^2)^2\end{align}$$

Now, just take the square root of this and integrate the result.

Comment: Thank you! I was so close to solving it. I had gotten it down to 9(1+t^2)(1+t^2) but failed to see it as 9(1+t^2)^2
I was able to solve it with your hint! Very helpful!

Comment: This is a very common set-up used in textbook exercises and exam problems (turning up a lot in problems related to arclength integration, for instance), in which the term to be added "flips the sign" in a binomial-square.  Don't be surprised to see this again...